# solving ODE using Existence & Uniqueness without initial value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let the ODE:

(E)  $  \pi y'\ = 4x\arcsin\left(\frac{y}{x^2+1}\right)$

Does (E) have a solution that goes through $(0,0)$. Is that solution unique?
If it's unique find it.

I tried to find solutions that solve this equation that goes through $(0,0)$ and then use the Existence & Uniqueness check to prove that this is the only one to solve it without success.
the difficulty to handle the $\arcsin$ in the equation, I know its continues for $x\in[-1,1]$ but it doesn't seem to help.

does $y=0$ the solution?

also, is the solution can go through $(0,1)$?

Comment: Yes, one should always check the roots of the right side and constant solutions.

For the solution through $(0,1)$ consider that this point is not inside the domain, but on its boundary. The solution may exist only on one side of $x=0$.

Comment: how I may prove that its the only solution with existence & uniqueness?

Comment: You can not. There are situations where more than one solutions end at a boundary point. Close-by at inner points you have of course existence and uniqueness, but have to explore if a limit to the given point exists.